# Practical Project Validation Error

Tags: javascript, html

Thank you for troubleshooting some of my code when I was attempting to run the validator.  I'm working on a math project and had more code here that I seem to be having more errors with.  I'm trying to work through the errors slowly but will retry in the morning.  What do you guys think?

```
      <!Doctype html>
      <head>
      <Title 1. Mathematics Review </title>
      <script type ='text/javascript'>
      Var someValue;
      someValue='2+2=4';
      someValue='5+2=7';
      alert (someValue);
      </script>
      </head>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of error in your code, I will explain them step by step.

In the first line, it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Next, in the third line, you are missing a > symbol and should not make the first letter in the tag  capitalized. So it should be:

```
<title> 1. Mathematics Review </title>
```

When you are declaring a variable in javascript, you should use var, not **Var**. The fifth line should be:

```
var someValue;
```

At line six and seven, I don't know what you want to do. 
If you are telling javascript to calculate an equation, you should do this:

```
someValue = 2+2 //not in qotes, and
someValue = 5+2
```

Comment: Thanks bud.  Ahh, valid HTML5! :)